# Python: Check if element is not in two lists?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I need to check if an element is not in two lists. I currently have:

```
if ele not in lista:
    if ele not in listb:
        do stuff
```

Using the following code did not work. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the above in python?

```
if ele not in lista and listb:
    do stuff
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if ele not in lista and ele not in listb:
    # do stuff
```

or

```
if ele not in lista + listb:
    # do stuff
```

but the second option will involve list concatenation which could potentially cause memory issues with large lists, also it will have to go through the list twice. To remedy this you could use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain
if ele not in chain(lista, listb):
    # do stuff
```

If you are going to be constantly checking for membership, you want to be using a `set` which has `O(1)` (amortized) lookup instead of `O(n)` for lists.

eg.

```
items_set = set(chain(lista, listb))
if ele in items_set:  # this membership check will be a lot faster
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I had tried the 'not in and' and was unsuccessful. I'll try the '+'

Comment: @user2084666 Did you try the 1st option verbatim? What you wrote, `if ele not in lista and listb`, is actually wrong and applies Python's boolean logic instead, you can look into that if you want but the way I have written it actually does work

Answer (score 3):

```
if ele not in lista and ele not in listb:
```

Answer (score -1):

late but I just wanted to add some more cool stuff

assuming both lists are of equal length

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = all("h" not in pair for pair in zip(a,b))
```

if they are of unequal length:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
c = all("h" not in pair for pair in zip_longest(a,b))
```